# Can regex return the position of the matched term?

Tags: regex

I use 'tags' (not sure of official regex term) to identify matches with regex. Can I specify the start/end position of the match inside the text block I am searching?

So if I were looking for "Yellow" in

I found a Yellow kite

it would return
Start: 11
Stop: 17

https://regex101.com/r/rK8fV8/1

Comment: Most regex implementations do return that, yeah. Which implementation are you using? I.e., which language/library?

Comment: This absolutely needs more information: without knowing what language/API you're using there's no way to tell how to get this done. Tag accordingly.

Comment: Right now I just stored the regex as you write then in regex101.com  As I see it these will be called via a mysql query (regexp) and scanning a text field in mysql table.  Alternately I suppose they could be called using a script using php regex with preg_match.

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose they could be called using a script using php regex with
>   preg_match.

That's right.

```
<?php
$subject = 'I found a Yellow kite.';
if (preg_match('/(?<COLOR>(Red|Blue|Yellow))/', $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
{
    $start = 1+$matches['COLOR'][1];
    $stop = $start+strlen($matches['COLOR'][0]);
    echo "Start: $start\nStop: $stop\n";
}
?>
```

With `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`, `$matches['COLOR']` is returned as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Yellow
    [1] => 10
)
```